# Using laser engraving for date stamping

Tags: stepper-motor, laser, arduino-uno

This is my very first big project. I have to build a laser engraving machine for date stamping. I'm using Arduino Uno microcontroller and a CNC shield with GRBL control.

Being fairly new to G-code, I looked up articles about writing one for daily date change. I found http://www.microtechstelladata.com/TextToNCcode.aspx where they convert date to G-code directly.

My concern is, how do I generate G-codes daily in an autonomous way? I am going to use another Arduino Mega for programming a keypad and an LCD screen and use it for controlling an RTC module for daily date update. Can I use the output of the RTC module somehow and feed it to the G-code generator in Arduino mega which will generate a G-code daily and provide it further to the other Arduino Uno board with the CNC shield.

RTC module (daily date update) --> Arduino Mega (generation of g-code for date provided by RTC module) --> Arduino UNO equipped with CNC shield and GRBL control --> stepper motors and laser diode driver --> laser engraving

Am I going in the right direction here? Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you looked at the control algorithms used for 3d printers?

Comment: Yes, I have. Did not find relevant information though.

Comment: Well, I am sure it’s out there - there were open-licence build your own plans with downloadable software...

Comment: I'll look it up some more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

G-code is vector based positioning. You can work in relative or absolute moves (I suggest the latter).

If you want to generate characters you'll need to find a vector (stroke) font you like and convert date text (from somewhere, the Arduino has no real-time clock) to G-code and then run a G-code interpreter to control the steppers and laser module.

Date information-> Date text -> Character movements for entire text-> G-code -> G-code interpreter-> Hardware

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will have to look it up, but now I know how to proceed. :)

Comment: You could try to control the steppers directly, but the G-code interpreter will provide scaling, linear and circular interpolation etc.

Comment: As for fonts, look up Hershey fonts; they are now publicly available, very pretty-looking vector fonts.